# Release Mongoose Memory Between Saves

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory

I'm using Mongoose to manage a MongoDB instance and I have data coming in at intervals. It comes out to about 300 distinct objects of about 9 key/value pairs each once every 5 seconds. Everything goes fine for a few minutes before the model size in memory starts to severely impact performance before finally tanking when it runs out of memory.

I've inspected the app with `node-inspect` to confirm that there aren't memory leaks in other parts of the app. It confirms that the persistence module which contains my Mongoose Model is where the memory is being used. Here's my save method:

```
function persistCoordinates(id, coordinates, callback) {
  var Usage = this.Usage;
  Usage.findById(id, pushCoordinates);
  callback();

  function pushCoordinates(err, usage) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    coordinates.forEach(push);

    function push(element, index, array) {
      if (usage) {
        usage.coordinates.push(element);
        usage.save(saved); // Just logs success. I suspect I need some cleanup.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've found this method of cleaning up, but if I'm understanding it correctly it'll remove my Model from memory entirely and muck up subsequent saves.

```
delete mongoose.models.Usage;
delete mongoose.connection.collections.usages;
delete mongoose.modelSchemas.Usage;
```

Am I misunderstanding what this does and, if not, is there a way to append to the `coordinates` array without having to keep the whole object in memory or load it in every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `callback();` without waiting for any of the async calls to complete looks suspicious, and you're calling `save` after each element is added instead of just once.

It would be more efficient to replace all that with an [`update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) that uses the [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) operator with [`$each`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) so that you're not re-loading the whole doc each time:

```
function persistCoordinates(id, coordinates, callback) {
  this.Usage.update({_id: id}, {$push: {coordinates: {$each: coordinates}}}, callback);
}
```

Comment: That callback was part of my debugging. Whoops! You're right about the save happening too often. I'll fix that and give your recommendation a go.

Comment: Looks like `update` is exactly what I needed. Thanks!